# Finding the first item in a python list which is big/small enough

Tags: python

Here is how I intend to do it:

```
def index_of_first_item_less_or_equal_than(lst, threshold):
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x <= threshold), math.inf)

def index_of_first_item_greater_or_equal_than(lst, threshold):
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x >= threshold), math.inf)
```

Comment: Promising to return an integer index, and then _sometimes_ returning a very large FP quantity is _not cool_. You've defined a Public API which is much too hard for diverse callers to correctly consume.

Comment: I’m curious about why you need to get the index rather than the element directly…

Comment: @301_Moved_Permanently Imagine partitioning around the element.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, I can imagine a handful of cases where you need the index, and a handful more where you don't. Except I shouldn't have to because there is concrete code that is using these functions; and questioning whether returning the index or the element directly could do for a perfectly valid answer, imho. But without enough context, that is not possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Good enough: maybe not**. Tastes and purposes vary, but I would say no. (1)
The current implementation is needlessly specific and repetitive. (2) The
defaults are not parameterized and their values are puzzling: the function is
supposed to return an index, unless in fails to find a match, in which case it
defaults to infinite? (3) The naming convention is awkwardly long and does not
scale well should you find yourself needing more functions like this.

**Start with a flexible foundation**. Because it's easy to do, we can begin
with a general utility function that borrows its name from
[more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.locate).

```
def locate_first(xs, predicate, default = None):
    gen = (i for i, x in enumerate(xs) if predicate(x))
    return next(gen, default)
```

**Add convenience helpers as needed**. Maybe that function is good enough for your
use case. If not, you can create conveniences like this:

```
def locate_first_gte(xs, threshold, default = None):
    pred = lambda x: x >= threshold
    return locate_first(xs, pred, default)
```

Comment: In .net, your first function is called `FirstOrDefault`,I think a variation on that would be better than locate…

Comment: @jmoreno Perhaps, but I'm skeptical. The or-default suffix is unhelpful: I'm glad Python doesn't have `next_or_default()`, `min_or_default()`, etc. (2) I considered "first" as a name by itself but thought it was ambiguous at best, and misleading at worst, in terms of whether it returns a value or an index.

Comment: I would prefer that next and min not have a default, not sure if that is a related argument or not...on thinking about it, perhaps it is.  If next with a default was instead next_or_default I'd be clearer both what it is and that it is undesirable.  Or maybe I'm just not pythonic enough.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Returning math.inf as the 'match not found' index seems like a poor API.**

I think I understand where the intention is coming from, since `-1` would be the most likely candidate value; but is also a valid python index.

You could return `None` as FMc suggests, or you could simply allow `next` to raise a `StopIteration`; yielding responsibility back to the caller to figure out how to handle things.

**2. Having repeated code is perfectly fine, in moderation**

I disagree with the other answer that claims your code is unnecessarily specific and repetitive. In fact, I would claim that their suggestion, whilst more flexible is in fact a **premature abstraction**. You have two, simple one-liner functions that do different things, sure they share some repeated logic, but they are simple and easy to understand at a glance.

Compare your version:

```py
def index_of_first_item_less_or_equal_than(lst, threshold):
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x <= threshold), math.inf)

def index_of_first_item_greater_or_equal_than(lst, threshold):
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x >= threshold), math.inf)
```

To the equivalent abstracted version suggested by FMc.

```py
def locate_first(xs, predicate, default = None):
    gen = (i for i, x in enumerate(xs) if predicate(x))
    return next(gen, default)

def locate_first_gte(xs, threshold, default = None):
    return locate_first(xs, lambda x: x >= threshold, default)

def locate_first_lte(xs, threshold, default = None):
    return locate_first(xs, lambda x: x <= threshold, default)
```

The abstracted version is necessarily **more complicated** than your version.
There is a place for such abstractions. I would suggest you avoid premature abstractions until you actually need the flexibility they offer, at which point you'll be better armed to choose a suitable abstraction.

Abstracting too early is a surefire way to end up with needlessly complex software.

**Conclusion**
Here's what I think I'd do in your shoes:

```
from typing import Sequence

def index_of_first_item_lte_than(sequence: Sequence, threshold: float) -> int:
    """Return the index of the first item less than or equal to `threshold`.

    :raises StopIteration: if no such item is found.    
    """
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x <= threshold))

def index_of_first_item_gte_than(sequence: Sequence, threshold: float) -> int:
    """Return the index of the first item greater than or equal to `threshold`.

    :raises StopIteration: if no such item is found.    
    """
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x >= threshold))
```